# How to 'pop' to a view contoller not on the stack

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

I have a navigation controller (XCode4 with Storyboards and ARC) where a segue is connected to each individual ViewController (7 of them).  Normally, I tap a row in the Nav contoller which takes me to the correct scene.  However, there are times that I want to go from scene "A" to scene "C" using segues, then from "C" to "B", which has NOT been placed on the stack by going through the Nav Controller.

Is this somehow possible (to go from scene "C" to scene "B")?

UPDATE:  this is the code to put controller on the stack:

```
EnterDataViewController *edvc = [[EnterDataViewController alloc]init];

NSMutableArray *ma = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
[ma insertObject:edvc atIndex:1];
self.navigationController.viewControllers = ma;
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex: 1] animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert the new view controller below the top one in the hierarchy, with animation off. Then, pop. :)

Comment: Wow!  sounds logical.... where do I find a doc or sample or a tutorial on how to do this?

Comment: I'd just read up on the `UINavigationController` documentation.

Comment: This appears to only handle items that are ON the nav stack... (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  Were you looking in the same place?

Comment: You can modify the `viewControllers` property of a navigation controller to change the stack *in situ*. So just get the old array, insert an object at `length - 1` (i.e. just before the last element), send `setViewControllers:animated:` with animation off, and then pop.

Comment: Insert didn't completely worked for me. Posted my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The stack is an array stored in the `UINavigationController's` `viewControllers` property. Use it to create a new (mutable) array where you could just `insertObject:atIndex:1` and assign this back to the `UINavigationController.viewControllers`.

Comment: NOTE Question UPDATED question...Added code as you suggested, but it always goes back to the navigation controller scene, not the one I want it to go to.

Comment: ma=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: self.navigationController.viewControllers]; leave the rest as you did.

Comment: Build error on [[ma insertObject:edvc atIndex:1];

No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'insertObject:atIndex:'

Comment: Is ma still declared as mutable array?

Comment: Changed it back to NSMutableArray... now get this error:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array'

Answer (score 0):

Inserting new controllers to the self.navigationController.viewControllers doesn't always work as expected, so I'd recommend to fetch controllers that you need from the array, build a new array from scratch, and then assign this array to navigation controller.

```
UIViewController *mainScreenController = [[self.navigationController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];  
SecondScreenController *secondScreenController = [[SecondScreenController alloc]init];     
NSMutableArray *controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:mainScreenController, secondScreenController, nil];    
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:controllers animated:YES];
```